# AWS Cost Explorer API not grabbing all data - NextPageToken possible issue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, while-loop, boto3

I have a script that successfully grabs cost data from AWS using boto3 and the cost explorer API. When I input the dates to give me data from Jan-Dec, I only get data from Jan-April. I then tried April-July and August-October and November-December and that worked/gave me the data. I am trying to get Jan-Dec data all from 1 run of the script but im not getting an error message. I believe it has to do with nextpagetoken and the while loop not correctly working. how do i fix the nextpagetoken part to give me all results?

**Paginator does not comply with this specific api call

My code is very similar to this:

https://github.com/hjacobs/aws-cost-and-usage-report/blob/master/aws-cost-and-usage-report.py

```
results = []

token = None
while True:
    if token:
        kwargs = {'NextPageToken': token}
    else:
        kwargs = {}
    data = cd.get_cost_and_usage(TimePeriod={'Start': '2020-01-01', 'End':  
'2020-12-10'}, Granularity='DAILY', Metrics=['AmortizedCost'],
                                GroupBy=[{'Type': 'DIMENSION', 'Key': 
'LINKED_ACCOUNT'}]} ,{'Dimensions': {'Key': 'LINKED_ACCOUNT','Values': 
['123948500267568']}}]}, **kwargs)
    for info in data['ResultsByTime']:
       for group in info['Groups']:
            print(group['Keys'][0], info['TimePeriod']['Start'], 
group['Metrics']['AmortizedCost']['Amount'])#, group['Keys'][1])
    token = data.get('NextPageToken')
    if not token:
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

here dimensions {'Dimensions': {'Key': 'LINKED_ACCOUNT','Values':
['123948500267568']}}]} should go in keyword argument "Filter" or try without adding it.

Reference  [Cost Explorer API](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ce.html#CostExplorer.Client.get_cost_and_usage)